# nodejs unit testing strategy: check if a table exists and contains the data you expect

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I have managed to unit test all the function that are using data from my database.

The problem starts when I want to check the data itself, what happens if the schema of my DB changed? All the other unit tests are using DB stubs and not the real data.

How can I check the schema of the DB? here I must not mock it, because I want to check the real schema.

Edit: Its important to note that the aforementioned DB is a third party one. I.e. I have checked all the functionality with mocks and now I want to check the acctual schema of this DB, just to make sure someone didn't changed it without mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

You will ideally write an *integration* test that roundtrips the data to/from your database.  You should use a local copy of the database in a clean state, not use a production/development or shared database.

If you're interested I wrote an [article](https://jaxenter.com/testing-the-database-layer-119366.html) on this a while back.  It's Java focussed but the theory holds true for pretty much any language

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, your advise is to load an in-memory instance of dev db that should be with the same schema like the production one. 

The problem is that I do not control the third party DB, how can I check it?

Comment: But you're integrating with their schema directly? Either ask for a schema or run tools to reverse engineer it for you.